# How do I use .get to retrieve multiple selections with a Listbox in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to make a program where one of the functions is to get the user's selected options from within a ListBox and display them on a pop-up window, and am stuck on where and how to use .get().

Here's the code:

```
        # Adds Listbox
        self.toppings_label = Label(self, text="Toppings:")
        self.toppings_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.toppings_selection = Listbox(self, selectmode="multiple")
        self.toppings_selection.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.toppings_selection.insert(1, "Pepperoni")
        self.toppings_selection.insert(2, "Sausage")
        self.toppings_selection.insert(3, "Green Peppers")
        self.toppings_selection.insert(4, "Olives")
        self.toppings_selection.insert(5, "Chicken")

        …

        toppings = self.toppings_selection.get()

        mb.showinfo("Confirm", "Toppings: " + toppings)
```

Comment: you can add `Button()` to run function (on button press) which use .get() to get selected data from listbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to process the multiple selections.  Of course instead of printing to the terminal, you could have an append inside the for loop to build your string which you would submit to the dialog box:

```
    selection = self.toppings_selection.curselection()
    for i in selection:
        print(self.toppings_selection.get(i))
```

Comment: I see my answer about multiple selections has appeared before my earlier answer to single selection, which is not the chronological order of the discussion, so please note that the code I am commenting on now does resolve the multiple selection question.

Comment: You can't expect answers to appear in any particular order. The order changes over time.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, now I cannot have a single selection go through without getting a TclError.

Comment: Please post your code and I'll have a look, because I am currently using this for both single and multiple selections without issues.